# UWP app cannot be found in Windows privacy settings

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, microphone

I have built an Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application in `C#` using Visual Studio 2017 Community (Version 15.4.2). My Operating System is Windows 10.

The app is supposed to use my local machine's microphone (in this case, my laptop's built-in microphone) to perform speech recognition.

The first thing I need to do is to let my app to be allowed to use the microphone. However, I can't find my newly created app in the list of apps in the privacy settings page.

[image]

---

However, if I use the sample projects downloaded from Microsoft website, it does show up in the list of apps:

### [image]

**My Question**: What do I need to let my app appear in the list of apps under the privacy settings page?

Comment: Request the permission in the Package Manifest

Comment: @JanMer Perhaps you want to show me the steps in your solution? Thanks for your comments here.

Comment: Right-Click your UWP sln > Properties > Package Manifest > Capabilities Tab > Click Microphone

Comment: I have never used the microphone but this worked for GPS and Network-Connection

Comment: @JanMer I just found it. It is showing up aleady. Thank you so much.

Comment: if you would like to use your mic on a android or ios device, there is something similar to this, basicially you just have to request permission for each platform

Comment: will leave a solution here for future users. Once again thank you v.much. I will reward you in another way & you will see it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user JanMer. To let Windows know your app needs to access the Microphone:

- Goto Solution explorer
- Double click Package.appxmanifest
- Click "Capabilities" Tab
- From the list of checkboxes, check "Microphone"

Run the app again, and revisit the privacy page. Now your app will show up in the list.

[image]
[image]